# Statue Park: Knight's Lines

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is a Statue Park puzzle.

Rules of Statue Park:

- Shade some cells of the grid to form the given set of pieces. Pieces may be rotated or reflected.
- Pieces cannot be orthogonally adjacent (though they can touch at a corner).
- All unshaded cells must be (orthogonally) connected.
- Any cells with black circles must be shaded; any cells with white circles must be unshaded.

[image: statue park puzzle whose piece bank is the pentominoes]

The piece bank is the 12 pentominoes, which have been given the standard lettering for your convenience -- the letters have no effect on the puzzle.

Comment: Not...(oh, boy)...not to question a moderator, but is the logical-deduction tag completely accurate here?

Comment: @Brandon_J Yes -- the puzzle has a unique solution that can (and should!) be found with pure logical deduction. There's no guessing required. (Though if this is your first Statue Park, it may be difficult -- I highly recommend tracking which cells are known shaded and unshaded. There's a walkthrough for an example solve of a simpler puzzle in [MellowMelon's Statue Park book](https://mellowmelon.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/puzzle-pack-2/) as well.)

Comment: This was short and sweet.  Nice!

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Thank you! I think this is one of my favorite logic puzzles I've made -- I was really happy with how a lot of the deductions worked out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cool Puzzle!  I had never seen these before.

Final Solution:

> [image]

Step 1:

> [image]
>  The tile must extend out.  It cannot connect to the next shaded cell because it would be size 6.  It cannot block off the unshaded cells, so it must therefor be the F tile.

Step 2:

> [image]
>  This is the only cell that is not a border and has no adjacent unshaded cells.  It must be the X tile

Step 3:

> [image]
>  Through extension and allowing the unshaded to attach, the top left is forced to U tile

Step 4:

> [image]
>  L tile is forced through extension and connection

Step 5:

> [image]
>  N tile is forced through extension and connection

Step 6:

> [image]
>  This is the only location that the I tile fits.

Step 7:

> [image]
>  All possibilities for tiles that fit in this location other than P were already used.

Step 8:

> [image]
>  With P used, that leaves only T for the bottom left corner.

Step 9:

> [image]
>  Through extension and connection, only Z fits in the bottom middle

Step 10:

> [image]
>  Through extension and connection, W is the only tile that fits on the left.

Step 11:

> [image]
>  The unshaded cell to the right and up blocked the V tile, so the Y tile is the only one that fits

Step 12:

> [image]
>  There are two possible orientations for the V tile.  One blocks off half of the puzzle and prevents connection, therefore only one orientation remains to solve the puzzle.

Comment: That's right! Could you add in an explanation of some of the major steps?

Comment: @Deusovi Completed as requested.

Comment: may i ask how you shaded the grids so easily? nice answer +1

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I saved the uploaded image and edited it with windows paint. I shaded using the bucket fill.

Comment: so the borders can be identified?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I do not understand your last question.

Comment: i originally mean how could paint recognise the borders as borders, but i tried it out, and it was fine. never mind, thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I have learned to never doubt the quality of a Deusovi puzzle.

Comment: lets chat at my home :) https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93544/oks-home