# Bobblie Statue Park

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is a Statue Park puzzle.

**Rules of Statue Park:** (shamelessly stolen from an earlier [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/84204) by @Deusovi)

> - Shade some cells of the grid to form the given set of pieces. Pieces may be rotated or reflected.
> - Pieces cannot be orthogonally adjacent (though they can touch at a corner).
> - All unshaded cells must be (orthogonally) connected.
> - Any cells with **black** circles must be **shaded**; any cells with *white* circles must be *unshaded*.

[image: the puzzle]

The piece bank is a set of [bobblies](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55771530#55771530), which (long story short) are little crowns with variable number of points. There are 4 no-point bobblies, 3 one-point bobblies, 2 two-point bobblies, and 1 three-point bobblie. I've labeled each with the number of cells they take up. The numbers and backstory have no effect on the puzzle.

---

Transcription of puzzle for those who have trouble with images

CSV:

```
,,,,w,,,,,b
,b,,,b,,,w,w,
,,b,,,,,,w,
w,,,w,,,,b,,w
,,,,b,,,,,
,,,,,b,,,,
b,,w,,,,b,,,b
,b,,,,,,b,,
,w,b,,,b,,,b,w
w,,,,,w,,,w,
```

There are 4 dominoes, 3 T-shaped tetrominoes, 2 C-shaped hexominoes, and 1 E-shaped octomino in the piece bank.

Comment: +1 for bobblies :-)

Comment: Bobblies! Nice puzzle :)

Comment: Nice! Did it take you longer to build this than it took Deusovi to answer it? (Difficulty-benchmark.)

Comment: Yep! I spent maybe ~10 hours constructing it, another hour checking, then another hour fixing a mistake, and another hour making the question & picture.

Comment: Well, Deusovi spent less than 45 minutes answering it :):)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To start,

> take a look at the lower right black cell. It *must* be part of a 4-piece; any other piece would rub up against a different black dot. And given the placement of two nearby black dots, there's only one way to actually fit it in.
>  [image]

And we can do the same thing again:

> Now the next two cells up the diagonal chain have the same deduction! We can't tell exactly how the piece will be placed yet, but it still has to be a 4 piece, or it'll run into a problem with the *next* black dot.
>  [image]

A big global deduction can be made:

> [image]
>  Consider the highlighted dots here. There are 7 red cells; each of them must be part of a separate shape. There are 4 more blue cells; we can only merge one pair of them (either the top two or the bottom two; if we do both the shapes will touch). So **this accounts for all 10 of our shapes.** In other words, each shape must cover at least one of these cells.
>
>  Now, *which dots can be 6s?* The only available 6 dots are A, D/E, and F: any other placement would either block off the "cubby" of the 6 shape, or brush up against a different known-shaded cell.
>  And *what about 8s?* C *must* have the 8: it can either pair with B, or go vertically by itself.
>  If it goes vertically, we have a problem: F's spot for the 6 is blocked off, and now we can't fit a piece in B while still pairing E-D. So **the 8 goes horizontally, covering B and C.**

And now the rest of the pieces fall into place:

> [image]
>  E must be a 2. I and J must also be 2s...
>  [image]
>  And now we need to place one more 4-piece -- if G and H are both ⊣-shaped, then D can't be extended without blocking off the path. So D is the other 4-piece, and the puzzle is solved!
>  [image]

Comment: I had a slightly different solving path to you, but not enough for a separate answer. My very first step (after trivial shading) was to try and place the 8 and two 6's. There are only two spots anywhere on the initial grid where the 8 can go, and only 3 for the two 6's. One of the 8-positions would block *two* 6's, permitting only one 6 to be placed. Thus the 8 must go where you placed it. One of the 6-spots then rubs up against the 8, so use the *other* two for the 6's - then continue. I do agree with an earlier comment of yours on this puzzle type - many interesting deductions! :)